# Does a C# parser generator that returns parse forests for ambiguous statements exist?

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, parser-generator, parse-forest

I would like to explore the use of formal language processing in the context of natural languages. To do so, I am searching for a parser generator that is robust to ambiguity in the sense that it won't denote EBNF as invalid when it multiple productions can be used to produce the same string. Furthermore, the standard way of handling redundancy is by returning parse forests instead of parse trees.

I am NOT asking what the best tool is, but only if there are tools that can be obtained for C#. And if there are, where can I find them.

It does not matter if the tool is open-source or proprietary.

The answer will be awarded to the longest list of unique (not mentioned earlier) tools which satisfy the required constraints on the parser returned by the parser generator.

Please help me explore parse forests.

Comment: Why should this be closed?

Comment: It's not for a homework project - I'm just exploring the space between formal langauage processing and natural language processing

Comment: Could someone who's marking this to be closed please provide feedback on why, so I stop asking questions that should be closed?

Comment: You're probably being down-voted because it's a question better suited for [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the link. Odd then that the other question I referenced was considered perfectly valid... But I'll give them a shot too.

Comment: I suppose I can see why it's marked as off topic. But I am not looking for "The Best" of something. I'm looking to see if such a tool exists at all, making the answer rather objective. It is more contrained than this question:  What is a good C# compiler-compiler/parser generator? - which was not flagged (though I appreciate that things change in 5 years). I feel like there must be a rewording that is possible to refactor this into a valid question.

Comment: SO has decided they don't like such questions (don't blame me). Try asking again at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find an implementation of Earley's Algorithm that does what you want, e.g. https://github.com/coonsta/earley

My own natural language engine (nlp.abodit.com) is based on an algorithm similar to Earley's.

Comment: Thank you. It doesn't have much web documentation, so I'm sitting down to start futzing. Does it compile a parser from EBNF? - i.e. is it a parser generator? Or is it simply a good open source parser?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't actually used that one, it was just an example of what to go look for.